# How to deal with anger that caused by nested problems?

Tags: psychology

Sometimes I encounter technical nested problems which are the problems that, the solution to a problem involves a sub-problems, which in turn has its own sub-problems. To deal with the anger I determine problems and create a list of them to identify what I am dealing with.

After some level,(Generally, 10 levels of nested problems) I can barely keep myself calm. Are there better techniques for controlling anger and stress levels with these nested problems?

Comment: 30 minutes of exercise a day, healthy body, healthy mind, happier person :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

If you feel as though there's too many sub-branches to the problem, then it's a good indication that the solution as a whole is far too complicated.

Take a step back and look at the larger problem as a whole and have a good re-think and address the problem again.